# VPN disconnects when removing from recent apps on Xiaomi devices

Tags: android, android-vpn-service

In my case I implemented CakeVpn (https://github.com/ashraf789/Cake-VPN) application as second module of project.

In original version from google play there's no problem with removing from recent.

And there's a problem on Xiaomi devices with my app that removing from recent apps causing VPN disconnect.

OnStartCommand is same with the original version

How can it be fixed?